# Error when generating multiple plots with ggplot in for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ggplot2, error-handling

I have a dataframe (tibble) in R from which I am trying to generate scatterplots and density plots using multiple columns of the dataframe with ggplot. I tried to use a for loop to print the code for each column but every time I am getting the following error.

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <tbl_df/tbl/data.frame>.
> Defaulting to continuous.
> Error in `data[[var]][scale_index[[i]]]`:
> Can't subset columns past the end.
> Locations 2, 3, 4, …, 999, and 1000 don't exist.
> There is only 1 column.

I tried the following code but getting this error every time I am trying to pass the y value as data[, i] using the for loop.

```
set.seed(1000)
data<- tibble(x=1:1000, y1=rnorm(1000), y2=rnorm(1000), y3=rnorm(1000))
```

```
> data
# A tibble: 1,000 × 4
       x     y1      y2     y3
   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 -1.37  -2.33    1.79 
 2     2  0.163  0.853  -1.04 
 3     3 -0.113 -0.557  -0.292
 4     4  0.860 -1.38   -1.79 
 5     5  0.129 -0.0861  0.514
 6     6  0.193 -0.378   1.69 
 7     7  0.390 -0.610  -0.698
 8     8 -2.23  -0.362   0.136
 9     9  1.03  -0.299   0.728
10    10  1.20  -0.0263 -1.16 
# ℹ 990 more rows
```

```
for (i in 2:ncol(data)){
     print(ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y= data[ ,i]))+geom_point())
     Sys.sleep(2)
 }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? And why I am getting this specific error?

Answer (score 0):

Each column of a tibble is itself a tibble. This is not what `ggplot()` expects for x and y values: it expects the name of a column, inside of `aes()`.

A better way to plot your data would be to transform it to a long format, with one column for the y-variable names and another for their values. Also, your example code overwrites each plot with the most recent. You might want to save each plot to a file, or consider using facets to show all 3 y-variables.

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The names of column is needed when rendering `ggplot()`.
You could do with names of columns in `for` loop.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1000)
data<- tibble(x=1:1000, y1=rnorm(1000), y2=rnorm(1000), y3=rnorm(1000))

for (i in names(data)[2:4]){
  print(
    ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y= .data[[i]]))+
    # ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y= get(i)))+ # OR using get()
          geom_point()
    )
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

[image][image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>